# how to load bunch of images to the Image in QML?

Tags: qml, qt-quick

I would like to load a few images to the Image object in QML. I want to do it one after another in a loop I think with some delay, because it should pretend to look like an animation. Im new in Qt and QML, so can anybody help me how to begin or somethin'? :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution, that works in QML 1.x and 2.0, is to use a `Repeater` and a `Timer` :

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: base;
    width: 800;
    height: 600;

    property variant images : [
        "image1.jpg",
        "image2.jpg",
        "image3.jpg",
        "image4.jpg",
        "image5.jpg"
    ];
    property int currentImage : 0;

    Repeater {
        id: repeaterImg;
        model: images;
        delegate: Image {
            source: modelData;
            asynchronous: true;
            visible: (model.index === currentImage);
        }
    }

    Timer {
        id: timerAnimImg:
        interval: 500; // here is the delay between 2 images in msecs
        running: false; // stopped by default, use start() or running=true to launch
        repeat: true;
        onTriggered: {
            if (currentImage < images.length -1) {
                currentImage++; // show next image
            }
            else {
                currentImage = 0; // go back to the first image at the end
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Should do it, and if you don't want the animation to restart when the last image is reached, just replace `currentImage = 0;` with `stop();` in the timer's `onTriggered`.

Also, you should possibly have to tweak a little the `Image` delegate in the `Repeater` to give it the look you want (size, fill mode, position etc...).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using QtQuick 2 then AnimatedSprite is the best way to do this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-effects-sprites.html

Otherwise, you could use a Timer or NumberAnimation to trigger changing the image source, but there could be unpredictable delays as images load for the first time (caching should solve this after the first loop).  If you only have a few images, you could have three Images and cycle their visibility.